# Android Studio Chipmunk provides features that can execute malicious code

Tags: android, android-studio, chipmunk

How I should react to this pop-up message?
I've selected the "safe mode" for now.

[Pop-up message after upgrading Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci2P5.jpg)

So then all projects seems to have this pop-up when opened first time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added the screenshot. This is showed since the new chipmunk version of Android studio has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

The new Patch 1 of Android Studio Chipmunk seems to fix this problem about "malicious code" on projects.